# SQL Server 2014 How to update record based on "masked" field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table of vehicles (see sample below).  When I receive symbol updates for this table, I only receive information for the VIN that contains the "&" (i.e. 2FM&K1FT).  The only difference between the & VIN and the VINs below it is the 4th character.  Updating the & VIN is easy enough (as shown).  After I have done that, how can I iterate through the other VINs and populate those records with the same symbols as the & VIN?

Is there a way for me to just match on the first 3 and last 4 characters that does NOT involve creating new columns with the  VIN split apart?

I am fairly new to SQL, so any help is greatly appreciated.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku3C5.jpg)

Comment: `where vin like '2fm_k1ft`? `_` is a `like` wildcard for "single character".

Comment: When you try to think of how to solve something with SQL, you should almost never think the word "iterate". Think in terms of sets.

Comment: I know I could use "like"..but there are, literally, hundreds of VINs like this with the "&".  I am trying to avoid actually hard coding any of them.  So, I'm looking for a solution that will allow me "scan" the database, stop when it finds on of these "&" VINs, populate VINs that match based on the 1st three and last 4 characters, and then continue.  Hope this is a better explanation of my problem.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You commenters actually understand this question?   I have no idea what he's asking.

Comment: Try this: UPDATE [MyTable]
   SET [VIN] = LEFT(VIN,3) + 'X' + RIGHT(VIN,4)
 WHERE 
  LEFT(VIN,3) = '2FM'
 AND RIGHT(VIN,4)= 'K1FT'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear exactly what you're asking, but if I understand correctly then this should work:

```
UPDATE V
SET
    sym = MU.sym,
    symcmp = MU.symcmp
FROM
    My_Updates MU
INNER JOIN Vehicles V ON V.vin LIKE REPLACE(MU.vin, '&', '_')
```